# Run a python source code on RAM

Tags: python

I have written a code which does some  processing , I want to reduce the execution time of the program and I think it can be done if I run it on my RAM which is 1GB. 

So will running my program form RAM make any difference to my execution time and if yes how it can be done.

Comment: Unless youve done something strange, your program is already loaded into ram when you tell it to run and when it loads the image file, that also goes to ram

Comment: ... the image **is* loaded to RAM when you read the file... moreover the code that does the IO is written in C, so it should be as fast as it can get. In other words: what you are saying doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, when you use a modernish computer system, most of your computation is done from RAM. (Well, technically, it's "done" from processor registers, but those are filled from RAM so let's brush that aside for the purposes of this answer)

This is thanks to the magic we call *caches and buffers*. A disk "cache" in RAM is filled by the operating system whenever something is read from permanent storage. Any further reads of that same data (until and unless it is "evicted" from the cache) only read memory instead of the permanent storage medium.

A "buffer" works similarly for write output, with data first being written to RAM and then eventually flushed out to the underlying medium.

So, in the course of normal operation, any runs of your program after the first (unless you've done a lot of work in between), will **already be from RAM**. Ditto the program's input file: if it's been read recently, it's already cached in memory! So you're unlikely to be able to speed things up by putting it in memory yourself.

Now, if you want to force things for some reason, you can create a "ramdisk", which is a filesystem backed by RAM. In Linux the easy way to do this is to mount "tmpfs" or put files in the /dev/shm directory. Files on a tmpfs filesystem go away when the computer loses power and are entirely stored in RAM, but otherwise behave like normal disk-backed files. From the way your question is phrased, I don't think this is what you want. I think your real answer is "whatever performance problems you think you have, this is not the cause, sorry".